# Zod compose a String and an Object parsers

Tags: typescript, zod

I have a parser

`stringParser` that would take a string (of a specific format, in my case query-like `k1=v1&k2=v2`) and with `transform` (OR `preprocess`, which is a lot less desirable because of the bug https://github.com/colinhacks/zod/issues/1460) and make a `Record<string,string>` out of it.

I have a `recordParser` that would parse this record's `k1/k2` keys and `v1/v2` values according to my schema where the keys and values are statically set (like `interface Parsed {k1: BrandedValue1, k2: BrandedValue2}`). But basically the `recordParser` is a vanilla `z.object(...)` parser.

How do I compose these two?

`stringParser.and(recordParser)` sounds strange to me (although I could be wrong) cause it doesn't define a "pipeline" semantically but rather "the value should be both of" (which a string is clearly not a Record for recordParser).

Calling `recordParser` inside `transform` of `stringParser` looks undesirable as well because of bad composition.

What's the best way / lesser evil to achieve such a composition?